# Get dats from week number of particular year

Tags: ios, swift

I need one function where i will pass any week number and year, that function should return dates for that week. Like if I pass week 2 and year 2016 then function should return me 3 January to 9 January.

Comment: See `NSCalendar`, it has exactly the functions to do that.

Comment: @Sulthan can you please post code, it will really help.

Comment: By the way, `3 January 2016` is the start of the *first* week in 2016. The first week of the year (WN 1) is the week containing January 4th or the first Tuesday of the Year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a very simple solution using `NSCalendar` functionality:

```
let week = NSDateComponents()
week.yearForWeekOfYear = 2016 // the year
week.weekOfYear = 10 // week index

let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()

// start of week or nil if the week does not exist
let weekStart = calendar.dateFromComponents(week) 

// add 1 week to start (this is essentially the start of the next week)
let weekEnd = calendar.dateByAddingUnit(.WeekOfYear, value: 1, toDate: weekStart!, options: [])

print(weekStart)
print(weekEnd)
```